# Is it possible to create an other endpoint in HTTP on the same port?

Tags: c#, http, wcf, net.tcp

One of my mate has created a C# WCF service working on Net.TCP on a specific port, it is asked to me if it is possible to create an other endpoint on this WCF service in order to consume it with HTTP protocol on the same port ?

How can I do to consume a WCF service with two differents protocols Net.TCP + HTTP ?

Thanks per advance for your answers :)

***Edit :***  Do you have an example about how to implement a HTTP + Net.TCP endpoints in a WCF service ?

Comment: It should be possible to share a port between [two TCP services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/net-tcp-port-sharing-sample) however this possibly won't work when one of the two is an HTTP listener.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wiktor Zychla. Do you have an example about how to implement a HTTP endpoint in a WCF service ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is completely impossible. But service could work properly over `Net.TCP+Http` over different port number.

```
<services>
      <service  name="ConsoleApp3.TestService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ConsoleApp3.ITestService" ></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="http" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleApp3.ITestService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:21012"/>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:21013"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
</services>
```

Net.TCP Port sharing only is applicable for the scenario that has different service addresses, not the indeed port sharing.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abraham Qian.  Do you have an example about how to implement a HTTP + Net.TCP endpoints in a WCF service ?

Comment: the above configuration is applicable for the self-hosted WCF service(console application). For the service hosted in IIS, just remove the base address in the above configuration from the WebConfig in default WCF project template, and then add the Http binding and Net.tcp binding in IIS site binding module.